# Expected Value of Truncated Random Variable

Tags: expectation

I have what appears to be a relatively simple question, but am struggling to understand how to go about answering it.

The general question is as follows:

What is the expected value of $S_{I}$, where:

$S_{I} = S$ if $S <3000 $

$S_{I} = 3000$ if $S >3000$

where $S$ is a compound distribution (details not necessary for my problem here)

My initial attempt is as follows:

$E[S_{I}] = E[E[S_{I}|S]] = E[S * P(S\leq3000) + 3000*P(S>3000)] = E[S]*P(S\leq 3000)+3000*P(S>3000).$

Now, from the definition of $S_{I}$, it is clear that we should have $E[S_{I}]<3000$. For this particular problem $E[S] = 4000$, and hence my proposed method for solving is wrong.

So I thought that my $E[S]$ in the line above should actually be $E[S|S\leq 3000]$

Is this assumption correct?

If so, is it true that $E[S|S\leq 3000] = E[S]*P(S\leq 3000)$ ??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is not generally true that $E(S|S\le 3000)=E(S)\Pr(S\le 3000)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Actually, this *might* be true for some specific distributions.

Comment: @Did: I amended, adding "generally."

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So what is $E[S|S\leq 3000]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=3000$, then
$$
E(S_{I})=E(S;S\leqslant x)+x\,P(S\gt x),
$$
and
$$
E(S_{I})=E(S\mid S\leqslant x)\,P(S\leqslant x)+x\,P(S\gt x).
$$